# 'Hearty' in Japanese

Tags: words, english-to-japanese, food

How would one say 'hearty' in Japanese? As in `hearty meal`, for example.

Comment: http://tangorin.com/general/hearty never heard it used though, so best I kept this a comment.

Comment: Another dictionary gives me たっぷり.

Comment: Isn’t this what a dictionary is for?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: The word hearty has a very nuanced meaning, almost bordering on an idiomatic expression. A dictionary is no help here... (and I've looked it up in several dictionaries before asking the question). I think that the simple fact that there has been no acceptable answer so far confirms that this is not something one could simply look up in any other dictionary.

Comment: The current question as is shows no evidence that you have made any effort to find the answer.  It is probably a good idea to state in the question what you already know and what you are unsure of.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a word that makes a one-to-one translation between English and Japanese. Unfortunately no such word exists. shin's answer literally means "heart warming", which is just one sense of the word "hearty". I wouldn't say that this question doesn't show research effort,  but you could stand to clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I do not know if the word “hearty” has particularly nuanced meanings, but even if so, my point stands: given the question “How do we say ‘hearty’ in Japanese?”, I do not think that anyone can do a better job than a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use:

> 食{た}べ応{ごた}えがある。

It's a well used idiomatic expression, representing something you eat that has kind of a resounding effect on how good you feel.  Hence, hearty.

Answer (score 2):

心あたたまるごはん。You can use kokoroattamaru.

Comment: I do not know which meaning of “hearty” the asker is thinking, but the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language (via [www.thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hearty)) says that “hearty” in _hearty meal_ means “Providing abundant nourishment; substantial,” which is different from 心温まる.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shot in the dark: 元気な (genkina): as in, 元気な食事 (genkina shokuji).

「元気な食べ物で元気なからだ作り」 Something like: "You are what you eat." (To be genki, eat genki.)